# Getting the largest Number of a key pair value in an Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, max, key-pair

So I'm trying to get which item has the largest number in 'size' inside the 'items' array. And print out which item as in ('item1','item2', 'item3')

```js
let items = [
  {
    item: 'item1',
    size: 545
  },
  {
    item: 'item2',
    size: 89
  },
  {
    item: 'item3',
    size: 789
  }
]
```

So I tried with

```js
let sizeMax = Math.max.apply(Math, items.map((o) => {
  return o.size;
}))
console.log(sizeMax)
```

but its not the ES6 way and i cant figure out how i can print the 'item' that has the largest size number
out the names 
I've been trying with:

```js
items.forEach((item) => {
  function arrayMax(item) {
  return items.size.reduce((h, j) => Math.max(h, j));
}
console.log(items.item)
```

but I cant quite figure what I'm not getting right

Answer (score 3):

You could take a spread syntax and map a destrucured property.

```js
let items = [{ item: 'item1', size: 545 }, { item: 'item2', size: 89 }, { item: 'item3', size: 789 }],
    max = Math.max(...items.map(({ size }) => size));

console.log(max);
```

For getting `item` of the largest `size`, you could reduce the array by taking the geratest size as accumulator then take the wanted property.

```js
let items = [{ item: 'item1', size: 545 }, { item: 'item2', size: 89 }, { item: 'item3', size: 789 }],
    max = items.reduce((a, b) => a.size > b.size ? a : b);

console.log(max.item);
```

Comment: I tried it and it does work but I was wondering how I could print out instead of the larger number, the item that has the larger number

Answer (score 2):

```js
let items = [
  {
    item: 'item1',
    size: 545
  },
  {
    item: 'item2',
    size: 89
  },
  {
    item: 'item3',
    size: 789
  }
]

let max = items.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc.size < curr.size ? curr : acc))

console.log('max item: ',max.item);
console.log('max size: ',max.size);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use lodash for this

[lodash maxBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#maxBy)

```
_.maxBy(items, 'size');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with array+object destructuring assignment:

```js
let items = [{item: 'item1',size: 545},{item: 'item2',size: 89},{item: 'item3',size: 789}];

const [ {item: max} ] = items.sort((a,b) => b.size - a.size);

console.log(max);
```